# Use Mathematica to save all citations from Google Scholar search

Tags: web-access

How can I save all citations from a Google Scholar search? For instance, in a search for "Radon transformation", there are about 35,500 results. I want to download all citations into a string - is there a simple way to get Mathematica to do that? (And sorry, no, I haven't tried anything yet. Not sure where to start.)

Comment: That surely would be against the fair use policy, wouldn't it?

Comment: @rhermans  I don't know - I haven't checked that. I am certainly not intentionally trying to do something that breaks their rules - I figured it would be fair to try. If it is against fair use, then never mind.

Comment: A few tens of queries surely are fine but 35K will make you noticed.

Comment: The policy states "Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide." I was hoping to use MMA to automate the "interface interaction" process, but maybe that violates the policy.

Comment: A colleague got locked out after doing a bunch of searches by hand. I guess a bot would get kicked out faster...

Comment: @rhermans, 
In September 2014, the SDNY upheld TVEye’s affirmative defense of fair use with respect to its core function of indexing news clips in a searchable database. The court reasoned that this indexing function is transformative because it [“converts copyrighted works into a research tool to further learning.”](http://www.tmtlawwatch.com/2015/09/southern-district-of-new-york-court-parses-fair-use-in-fox-news-copyright-infringement-dispute-with-media-monitoring-service/)

Answer (score 7):

This could get you strated

```
gsq[str_String] := Block[{url},
  url = "https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=" <> 
    URLEncode[str] <> "&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=";
  Cases[
   Cases[
    Import[url, "XMLObject"]
    , XMLElement["div", {"id" -> "gs_ccl", "role" -> "main"}, ___], 
    Infinity]
   , XMLElement["h3", {"class" -> "gs_rt"}, ___], Infinity]
  ]
```

Use *"inspect element"* in your browser to understand the *div  ids*.

Answer (score 6):

(This is an abbreviated version of a [post on my blog](https://jschrier.github.io/blog/2024/03/13/Automated-Bibliometrics-with-GoogleScholar-and-OpenAlex.html)

## Google Scholar (via scholarly)

GoogleScholar is not really intended for programmatic access, and you may also hit usage limits.  That being said, python packages like [scholarly](https://scholarly.readthedocs.io) exist to do this, and if you make only a few requests, you should be fine:

```mathematica
(* install the python package *)
ResourceFunction["PythonPackageInstall"]["scholarly"];

(* create a python session and function to get the first 10 results *)
session = StartExternalSession[
    <|"System" -> "Python", 
     "SessionProlog" -> "from scholarly import scholarly"|>] ;
 
searchPubs = ExternalFunction[session, 
  "def search(terms):
    query = scholarly.search_pubs(terms)
    results = []
    for i in range(10):
      results.append(next(query))
    return results"];

(* demo: perform the search *) 
example = searchPubs["Radon transform"];

(* extract information from the result *)
Dataset @ Query[All, "bib", {"pub_year", "author"}] @ example
```

## A Better Way: OpenAlex API

[OpenAlex](https://openalex.org) is an open project that makes it easy to get data.  The easiest way is get started is to do a text search through the web, and then click the gear button to generate the corresponding API query:

[image: screen snapshot of an OpenAlex web search]

It is then straightforward to copy and execute the corresponding API query in using [URLExecute](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLExecute.html) (you may of course modify it to suit your needs:

```mathematica
example2 = URLExecute["https://api.openalex.org/works?page=1&filter=default.search:radon+transform&sort=relevance_score:desc&per_page=10"]; 
 
Dataset @ Query["results", All, {"publication_date", "doi"}] @ example2
```

OpenAlex has many other powerful features, including (machine-learned) topic groupings, links to open access versions of documents, etc.  The [documentation is excellent.](https://docs.openalex.org)